# ITextsharp 5.5 crashes when reading a file (but ITextsharp 4.6.1 not crashes )

Tags: itext

We work with Itextsharp in version 5.5

There are damaged pdf files that do not open in this version but open in version 4.6.1.

The code:

```
  public static async Task<byte[]> FlatPdf(byte[] pdfFile)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);


            byte[] newBuffer = null;

            try
            {
                PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;           
                MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

                using (PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream) { FormFlattening = true })
                {
                    stamp.Close();
                    newBuffer = outStream.ToArray();
                }

                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggerEx.GetLogger().Error($"Error occurred while Flattening process,\n Exception: {ex}");
            }

            return newBuffer;

        }
```

The exception occurs on this line :

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
```

The Exception is:

```
Rebuild failed: Unexpected '>>' at file pointer 1846; Original message: Unexpected '>>' at file pointer 1846
```

We don't want to downgrade.
What can be done to be able to read the file even if it is slightly damaged (in our itext version)?

Comment: The error checking improved in itext 5.5. Can you open those files in tools like *crobat? You would have to provide an example file here because this is a really specific problem

Comment: I can open the pdf in Acrobat.